# change shape of DataFrame for grouping

Tags: python, pandas

my question is below.

source :

```
ID  subID_1  value_1   subID_2  value_2  subID_3  value_3
--  -------  -------  --------  -------  -------  -------
A    aaa       10       abb       30       acc       40
B    baa       20       bbb       60       NaN       NaN 
C    caa       50       NaN       NaN      NaN       NaN
```

hope :

```
ID  subID  values  
--  -----  --------  
A    aaa     10          
A    abb     30      
A    acc     40      

B    baa     20      
B    bbb     60      

C    caa     50
```

I tried it using 'unstack()' but result is different comared to what I wanted.
Please help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create index from column `ID` if necessary by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) columns for `MultiIndex`, so possible reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html). Last data cleaning - double [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) - first for remove second level of MultiIndex and second for column from first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df.set_index('ID')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df)
  ID subID  value
0  A   aaa   10.0
1  A   abb   30.0
2  A   acc   40.0
3  B   baa   20.0
4  B   bbb   60.0
5  C   caa   50.0
```